# WSO2 ESB- how to retrieve a property value that has xml tags using XLST mediator, all I get its '&lt;' for '<'

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am working on WSO2 ESB proxy service, where XSLT transformation needs to be done, taking a section of values from an xml and combine with the result of another .dsb file

Here is my  property that has below value

```
*<xslt key="conf:/input/proxy_input_transform.xslt"/>
<property name="DETAILS" expression="//QUARTERLY_DATA" />
<QUARTERLY_DATA>
<ROW>
<SAP_CUST_ID>0000905133</SAP_CUST_ID>
<AOC_FLAG>N</AOC_FLAG>
<LOB>AppleCare</LOB>...."
```

but when a xlst is done after calling the .dbs file in the outsequence

```
   <xslt key="conf:/output/proxy_output_transform.xslt" >
      <property name="details" expression value="get-property('DETAILS')"/>
   </xslt>
```

I get the value in the transformed xml like the one below.

```
&lt;QUARTERLY_DATA>
&lt;ROW>
&lt;SAP_CUST_ID>0000905133&lt;/SAP_CUST_ID>
&lt;AOC_FLAG>N&lt;/AOC_FLAG>
&lt;LOB>AppleCare&lt;/LOB>....
```

I am not sure as why the "<" is getting changed to "&lt;".
 Could someone give their findings on this?
 Note:I was able to successfully retrieve the value from  property, that has just single      value instead of the XML tags. Having the type as "OM" in property worked while placing the xml in the message context.
Here is my proxy service

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TQS_SIST_BILLING_PCH_N" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="enable" statistics="enable">
    <target>
    <inSequence onError="conf:/tqs/common/FaultHandler_Seq.xml">
        <property xmlns:sist="http://sist.tqs.ist.apple.com/sist_request" name="IN_SAP_SOLD_TO" expression="//sist:ACC_BILLING_REQ_PCH_FLAG_N/sist:CUST_SRCH_INPUT/sist:SAP_SOLD_TO"/>
        <xslt key="conf:/tqs/sist/billing_pch_n/proxy_input_transform.xslt"/>
          <property name="REQUEST" value="DETAILS_REQUEST"/>
            <property name="SAP_CUST_ID" expression="//ACC_BILLING_REQ_PCH_FLAG_N" type="OM"/>
                <send>
                    <endpoint key="conf:/tqs/sist/billing_pch_n/ds_endpoint.xml"/>
                </send>
     </inSequence>
    <outSequence onError="conf:/tqs/common/FaultHandler_Seq.xml">
        <switch source="get-property('REQUEST')">
            <case regex="DETAILS_REQUEST">
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="sequence" value="outSequence - response from Details Service"/>
                </log>
                <property name="DETAILS" expression="//QUARTERLY_DATA"/>
                <log level="custom" separator=",">
                    <property name="DETAILS------at entry level" expression="get-property('DETAILS')"/>
                </log>
                <enrich>
                    <source type="property" clone="true" property="SAP_CUST_ID"/>
                    <target type="body"/>
                </enrich>
                <log level="full">
                    <property name="sequence" value="outSequence - request for Summary Service"/>
                </log>
                <property name="REQUEST" value="SUMMARY_REQUEST"/>
                <send>
                    <endpoint key="conf:/tqs/sist/billing_pch_n/ds_summary_endpoint.xml"/>
                </send>
            </case>
            <case regex="SUMMARY_REQUEST">
                <log level="full">
                    <property name="sequence" value="outSequence  - response from Summary Service"/>
                </log>
                <log level="custom" separator=",">
                    <property name="DETAILS------222222" expression="get-property('DETAILS')"/>
                </log>
                <xslt key="conf:/tqs/sist/billing_pch_n/proxy_output_transform.xslt">
                    <property name="details" expression="get-property('DETAILS')"/>
                </xslt>
                <send/>
            </case>
        </switch>


    </outSequence>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in your xslt, you may used the "output method" as text.Use  `output method="xml"`

eg:  `<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />`

Comment: Thanks for reply!
Nope, I did not use text.This is the xslt I had used 

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />|
......

Comment: Can you post your synapse configuration?

Comment: It is too long for me to post

Comment: OK.Soemwhere you point the output/message as text not as xml. that is why you see the above issue.

Comment: Added the proxy service I had written at the questionnaire section.
By Synapse config, do u mean proxy service?

Comment: yes i meant the proxy conf..Before sending to xslt mediator waht is the following log prints (use log level as "full" and check)? <log level="full" separator=",">
                    <property name="DETAILS------222222" expression="get-property('DETAILS')"/>
                </log>   and when you dircetly passing that as input for your xslt script does that work without any issue?(ie: using an xslt tool,like eclipse)

Comment: yes , it works perfectly before xslt.Logs show the correct values i.e, "<QUATERLY_DATA>...".It is only after XSLT does the "<" value change to "&lt;". I had used <xsl:copy-of select="$details"> in the XSLT file to get the param value (i.e, the property value of proxy service).

As an alternate, I proceeded to build the xml using enrich mediator and it worked.

Comment: SO, issue is in your XSLt script and yes "copy-of" should work for XMLs..not sure what is the issue

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out.I was not sure myself, hence took a different approach of building the xml via enrich mediator that WSO2 esb provided.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to edit the configuration files by directly accessing the .xml files of your configuration. Just do all of your configuration edits using a text editor and try to run your scenario. Sometimes when you are editing configurations in the management console, this kind of characters are included in the config files. Can you try with this?