# how to use lookups in xslt mediator in wso2esb

Tags: xslt, properties, wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

In WSO2ESB, using the xslt mediator, I want to transform a webservice result. I do that using an xslt file. In this file, I want to do some lookups, to transform some values into something else.

In Oracle, you can use a dvm for that.

In plain xslt, it looks like the document('somefile.xml') function could do the trick, but WSO2ESB looks for the xml file on the filesystem, and the resources property on the xslt mediator does not translate document() contents into correct paths.
Then, I tried inputting the XML by reading it into a property in ESB, and then pass the property to the mediator. This also does not work, because the content of the XML is then 
passed as one string value instead of a nodeset.

Am I doing something wrong - what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: This looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784197/wso2-esb-how-to-retrieve-a-property-value-that-has-xml-tags-using-xlst-mediator - the passed param is turned into a string and escaped, so it is not xml-parsable and cannot be used in expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can inject the content of your document 'somefile.xml' as a subtree inside the current message before invoking XSLT mediator :

Define a local entry named 'somefile' with the content of 'somefile.xml'

Use enrich mediator to inject it's content inside current message :

```
<enrich>
  <source clone="true" xpath="get-property('somefile')"/>
  <target type="body" action="child"/>
</enrich>
```

In your XSL transformation, use this content rather than refering to $somefile/xxx...
(and forget this content in the result)

Comment: This for me is the simplest solution: first, create a property and lookup the file using get-property('registry', 'conf:/custom/somefile.xml'), then inject it in the body using enrich.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the XSLT mediator acts on the message body, so shouldn't be necessary to use the document function to load the XML seperately.  For an example of the xslt mediator, see [this link to the current wso2esb documentation](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Sample+8%3A+Introduction+to+Static+and+Dynamic+Registry+Resources+and+Using+XSLT+Transformations).

If you want to replace a few values in your XML, you may want to try the enrich mediator.  The enrich mediator can use Xpath expressions to select the source and target expressions for replacement.

Comment: What I need the document function for, or replacement function, is this: to replace coded values from one service with coded values from another. Example: Replace M/F/U (male/female/unknown) with M/V/O (dutch translation), or another list, with for example a 100 codes that need to be mapped.  
These mappings are stored in a separate file, which needs to be loaded.   
In one message body, there can be multiple codes like this: country codes, city codes, etc. To do this using the enrich mediator would involve for example 5-10 mediators, which is not very efficient.